# Create AD User using multiple input prompts

Tags: powershell

I want to create AD user by asking prompts from user input one by one.
I searched the script from google. See below.

```
    $title = "Login"
$message = "Please enter your information to login!"
$name = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription "Name"
$name.Label = "&Login Name"
$name.DefaultValue = "Guest"
$pwd = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription "Password"
$pwd.Label = "&Password"
$pwd.SetparameterType( [System.Security.SecureString] )
$pwd.HelpMessage = "Please type your Password."
$fields = [System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription[]]($name, $pwd)
$login=$Host.UI.Prompt($title, $message, $fields)
```

How to pass these parameters in below old statement

```
New-ADUser -Name “Charlie Russel” `
           -AccountPassword "testing"  `
           -SamAccountName 'Charlie’ `
           -DisplayName 'Charlie Russel’ `
           -EmailAddress 'Charlie@TreyResearch.net’ `
           -Enabled $True `
           -GivenName 'Charlie’ `
           -PassThru `
           -PasswordNeverExpires $True `
           -Surname 'Russel’ `
           -UserPrincipalName 'Charlie’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it using `$login.Name` and `$login.Password`:

```
New-ADUser -Name 'Charlie Russel' `
           -AccountPassword $login.Password  `
           -SamAccountName $login.Name `
           -DisplayName 'Charlie Russel’ `
           -EmailAddress 'Charlie@TreyResearch.net’ `
           -Enabled $True `
           -GivenName 'Charlie’ `
           -PassThru `
           -PasswordNeverExpires $True `
           -Surname 'Russel’ `
           -UserPrincipalName 'Charlie'
```

Comment: how to display $name.Label = "&Login Name" values on prompt every time instead of FieldDescription